# Spark is not started automatically on the AWS cluster - how to launch it?

Tags: apache-spark

A spark cluster has been launched using the ec2/spark-ec2 script from within the *branch-1.4* codebase. I have logged onto it.

I can login to it - and it reflects **1 master, 2 slaves**:

```
11:35:10/sparkup2 $ec2/spark-ec2  -i ~/.ssh/hwspark14.pem  login hwspark14
Searching for existing cluster hwspark14 in region us-east-1...
Found 1 master, 2 slaves.
Logging into master ec2-54-83-81-165.compute-1.amazonaws.com...
Warning: Permanently added 'ec2-54-83-81-165.compute-1.amazonaws.com,54.83.81.165' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Last login: Tue Jun 23 20:44:05 2015 from c-73-222-32-165.hsd1.ca.comcast.net

       __|  __|_  )
       _|  (     /   Amazon Linux AMI
      ___|\___|___|

https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2013.03-release-notes/
Amazon Linux version 2015.03 is available.
```

But .. where are they??   The only java processes running are:

- Hadoop: NameNode and SecondaryNode
- Tachyon: Master and Worker

It is a surprise to me that the Spark Master and Workers are not started.  When looking for the processes to start them manually it is not at all obvious where they are located.

Hints on

- why spark did not start automatically

and

- where the launch scripts live

would be appreciated. (In the meantime i will do an exhaustive

```
 find / -name start-all.sh
```

And .. survey says:

```
root@ip-10-151-25-94 etc]$ find / -name start-all.sh
/root/persistent-hdfs/bin/start-all.sh
/root/ephemeral-hdfs/bin/start-all.sh
```

Which means to me that spark were not even installed??

**Update**  I wonder: ***is this a bug in 1.4.0***?  I ran same set of commands in 1.3.1 and the spark cluster came up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a [bug](https://github.com/mesos/spark-ec2/commit/53225b0091f31c56db36fb0a6b98e5506face2ec) in spark 1.4.0 provisioning script which is cloned from github repository by spark-ec2 (https://github.com/mesos/spark-ec2/) with similar symptoms - apache spark haven't started. The reason was - provisioning script failed to download spark archive.

Check was spark downloaded and uncompressed on the master host `ls -altr /root/spark` there should be several directories there. From your description looks like `/root/spark/sbin/start-all.sh` script is missing - which is missing there.

Also check the contents of the file `cat /tmp/spark-ec2_spark.log` it should has information about uncompressing step.

Another thing to try is to run spark-ec2 with other provisioning script branch by adding `--spark-ec2-git-branch branch-1.4` into the spark-ec2 command line argument.

Also when you run spark-ec2 save all output and check is there something suspicious:

```
spark-ec2 <...args...> 2>&1 | tee start.log
```

Comment: Yes this is what caught me.  Significant time drain yesterday. Pls consider upvote the question.

Comment: I hear you. I spent two evenings because it - I was looking into the other bug and they've updated provisioning script to contain this bug.